# Are $n$-dimensional manifolds locally homeomorphic to $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ or the more general real space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: manifolds

Many if not most authors use the term “$n$-dimensional Euclidean space” as synonymous with “$n$-dimensional real space”, $\mathbb{R}^n$. Some, however chose to be more rigorous and use the term Euclidean space and the symbol $\mathbb{E}^n$ to specifically refer the metric real space equipped with the usual Euclidean distance function, whereas the general real space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of real $n$-tuples, which is not necessarily equipped with additional structure such as a metric.

Considering this distinction, are $n$-dimensional manifolds locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{E}^n$ or just to $\mathbb{R}^n$? In other words, do the codomains of the coordinate maps of charts in a manifold’s atlas have to be open subsets of a metric space with a distance function?

Comment: If your local identification is by homeomorphisms, then Euclidean space is equivalent to $\mathbb R^n$. The topological category knows nothing about the metric. If you really want to have Euclidean charts (with Euclidean transition functions), then you're getting into geometric structures.

Comment: Got it, of course. If the open set of the chart is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is also homeomorphic to $\mathbb{E}^n$. The metric is irrelevant so saying that the manifold is locally Euclidean doesn’t mean the manifold has a corresponding metric. Thanks!

Comment: More precisely, they mean $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the standard topology.

Comment: Thanks. Isn’t “$\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the standard topology” precisely the $n$-dimensional Euclidean metric space since the standard topology’s basis consists of open balls (or equivalently open cubes) defined using the Euclidean distance function?

Comment: Topology is not the same as metric (you cannot say "topology is a metric"). You can say that the standard topology is induced by the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, and chewing on this a bit more, I now see the gap in my thinking on what may be a somewhat nitpicky point.

A homeomorphism is by definition a function between *topological* spaces. So when we say that every point in a manifold is an element of an open set which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ we mean to an open set of the *topological* space “$\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology”. The standard topology is induced by the Euclidean metric so this topological space is in fact the Euclidean metric space $\mathbb{E}^n$. So the shorthand description of a manifold as “locally Euclidean” is not as loose as I had thought. One does in fact need the Euclidean metric to induce a the standard topology on plain old $\mathbb{R}^n$, but this does not imply that the manifold itself is equipped with a metric.